# How did George get the antidote?

Tags: plot-explanation, rampage

In the movie Rampage,

> Davis and Kate make a plan to steal a counter-serum, hoping that they
>   can turn the mutated animals back to normal. They are able to reach
>   Energyne headquarters at the Willis Tower and take several vials of
>   the serum, they are caught by Claire and Brett. When George climbs up
>   to the top of the tower, Claire orders Davis to distract him while she
>   attempts to escape with Kate held hostage. Kate slips a vial into
>   Claire's handbag and pushes her towards George, who eats Claire alive
>   along with the serum.

([from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampage_(2018_film)))

Goerge eats Claire's handbag with the serum. The vial itself is made with either some kind of plastic and/or rubber mixture. How did serum goes into George's body/his bloodstream?

Did he digested the handbag along with Claire and after digestion, serum went into his bloodstream? I didn't notice vial dropping down from Claire's bag while George eats her.  Note that George get the antidote only after few minutes after eating Claire+Vial. Even if he could digest handbag+vial, it may take some time to digest and go into blood stream.

Or is it something else that I've missed?

Answer (score 6):

## We need to assume he immediately assimilated the antidote after swallowing Claire.

As you said, Kate puts the serum inside Claire's handbag. Claire then gets swallowed **whole** by George, and a few minutes later, George is cured. This is movie logic, digestion takes hours, and George did not chew her. Also, most serums are administered intravenously, so that they enter the blood stream faster. Usually ingesting an antidote does not work.

In other words, we just have to assume that A) this antidote can be swallowed, B) George eats and either chews or immediately digests the purse and serum container.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't watch the movie, but usually things you eat get chewed before swallowing, so the vial could have been destroyed that way. It would even be plausible that the gorilla's gums were injured in the process, allowing a quicker absorption into the bloodstream.

Personally though, I'd advise not to dig too deeply into the logic of a movie like this. ;-)

Edit: Since, as @Vishwa pointed out, nobody gets chewed, this seems to be another case of a [Magic Antidote](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicAntidote) (careful, TV Tropes ahead). This also explains that a multi-ton mammal undergoes a gene therapy in minutes.

Comment: Although I agree with your advice, George did not chew Claire or her bag. they just went inside George very peacefully ;) Antidotes usually contain complex proteins right? so ingesting them wont work. Proteins get destroyed while digesting. That's why we inject.. anyway, appreciate the answer :)

Comment: @Vishwa Alright, edited the answer accordingly.